# How to source .bashrc when starting Rstudio Server

Tags: r, unix, rstudio

I'm running R Studio server. I need to set a bunch of parameters to get spark working that I typically do using

`source myParamFile.sh`

via the shell.

I would like it to be sourced automatically via R studio without recopying all the parameters to a different location. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, but why your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36488270/how-to-append-two-series-into-a-dataframe-row-wise) was deleted? I think I find solution - `pd.concat([maxRow,minRow], axis=1).T`

Comment: Found the answer :-).

Comment: It is sad for me, because today I have only [196](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael?tab=reputation) points and I hope maybe 10 points get  from you for answer, because I would like 200 points today. But it is up to you if undelete quesion :) If yes or not, no problem. Nice day.

Comment: How do I undelete a post?

Comment: Bellow text of [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36488270/how-to-append-two-series-into-a-dataframe-row-wise) are links - share edit close undelete flag. Click to undelete. Thank you.

Comment: undeleted. Please feel free to like the question as well :-).