# How to append two series into a dataframe Row wise

Tags: python, pandas

I have two series

```
maxRow
Out[160]: 
var#0         2.175999
var#1         1.016451
var#2         0.705303
var#3         1.842707
var#4         1.196601
var#5         2.162564
var#6         1.350877
var#7         0.453014
var#8         2.144554
obj#0    445537.407762
Name: 9, dtype: float64

minRow
Out[161]: 
var#0        2.593331
var#1        1.990545
var#2        2.011221
var#3        1.349357
var#4        2.808741
var#5        0.890439
var#6        1.275528
var#7        1.658743
var#8        2.343061
obj#0    51386.375391
Name: 10, dtype: float64
```

What I would like to do is combine them *row-wise*.

Thus the first row will go from 2.175999 to 445537.407762.

The next row will go from 2.593331 to 5.1386.375391.

I know ahead of time that the series length will be consistent. I tried finding this but could only find examples of appending column-wise.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
print pd.concat([maxRow,minRow], axis=1).T

       var#0     var#1     var#2     var#3     var#4     var#5     var#6  \
9   2.175999  1.016451  0.705303  1.842707  1.196601  2.162564  1.350877   
10  2.593331  1.990545  2.011221  1.349357  2.808741  0.890439  1.275528   

       var#7     var#8          obj#0  
9   0.453014  2.144554  445537.407762  
10  1.658743  2.343061   51386.375391
```