# Combining two series into a dataframe row wise

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation, series

I'm trying to merge two series into one single row in a new dataframe and then add more rows into it. For example, I have series as below:

```
s1

var1       10
var2        9
var3        2

s2
var4        1
var5       81
var6       13
```

I want to make them into a dataframe like this:

```
    df
    var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6
 0    10     9     2     1    81    13
```

The closest solution I can find is this: [How to append two series into a dataframe Row wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36488270/how-to-append-two-series-into-a-dataframe-row-wise)

However if we do this we'll get something like this:

```
result = pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1).T
print(result)

    result

    var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6
 0    10     9     2   NaN   NaN   NaN
 1   NaN   NaN   NaN     1    81    13
```

which is clearly not what we want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

alternative solution:

```
In [72]: pd.concat([s1,s2]).to_frame().T
Out[72]:
   var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6
0    10     9     2     1    81    13
```

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly! It took me hours searching on the internet and couldn't find a solution. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

#### Setup

```
s1 = pd.Series([10, 9, 2], ['var1', 'var2', 'var3'])
s2 = pd.Series([1, 81, 13], ['var4', 'var5', 'var6'])

pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([s1, s2])).T

   var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6
0    10     9     2     1    81    13
```

Comment: Works! Thanks! I'm still pretty new to pandas. The difference between dataframes and series really confuses me sometimes. I think your example gives me some ideas about how it works. Thanks a million!